# Factory reset without resetting settings

Tags: factory-reset, sony-xperia

On a Sony Xperia, there is a way.to reset the settings, and not data. Is there a way to reset the data, without resetting the settings. I am not accepting any methods needing root. I find it a hassle to even look for the bootloader on this thing.

Why? I have a tank setup for my battery, and all sorts of power optimization settings. (They are Xperia only settngs)I don't want them reset when I clear my data

Using Sony Xperia E C1505

Comment: @Firelord I wouldn't say "rude" – but indeed, that reduces chances dramatically. // **Dan:** can you be a bit clearer how to identify those "settings"? Apps usually store their settings together with their data. Is it a specific app you want to retain its data? Afraid it's not possible to separate the two; that Sony feature you're referring to most likely relates to *specific* (device/account) settings. // Related: [Clearing all the app data on an Android tablet without using factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115315/16575)

Comment: @Izzy The choice and usage of words could've been different, yet making the same meaning. // But anyhow, I don't understand the question much so I can't really post an answer, be it requiring root access or not.

Comment: @Firelord full ack to the second part. But I disagree on the first – except for the phrasing, maybe :) Rooting your device is not always an option, for many possible reasons.

Comment: Consider: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34645/what-can-be-saved-before-factory-reset

Comment: @Firelord I should explain... I have a broken build.prop. I CANNOT ROOT., WHATEVER I TRY. Theres only so many time you can try to get an Apple from the tree and continue when you fail

Comment: @JohanShogun Not what I am looking for. Izzy and firelord, your points have been taken in :). But, Izzy, your related question was not what I needed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The settings you speak of, are they settings built into the phone or from 3rd party apps? There are non-root apps that can back up apps and data for you. If it's not from a 3rd party app, you could try pulling the data off the phone via adb and factory reset then push the data back to the phone. Just make sure to remove the broken build.prop from the data you pull, so that you don't overwrite it when you push it all back. There is a lot you can do with adb, just have to know what to type. Once again not 100% this will do what you are asking. But at the very least worth looking into.

Comment: I have already  tried that.  BTW,  it is the system settings